# Azure Stream Analytics to Sql

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I use Azure IoT Hub and Stream Analytics to write messages which comes from devices to Sql. Every message has a device id. I need to determine database name from device id. I have a master database which stores device id and database name. How can I do that? Can I parse the message in IoT hub and send different stream analytics job? Is it possible parse message inside a stream analytics job and send different outputs according to device Id?

Comment: In other words, you want to lookup the database name. Check the docs on lookups [Using reference data for lookups in Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wonder is it best practice using only one streaming job and send messages to different outputs.

Comment: [Azure SQL Database output from Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-database-output)